# Shell or PERL script - run multiple queries based on current active table

Tags: perl, shell, sqlplus

I am hoping someone can help me with my shell script. I have a file that lists different table prefixes.

The file looks like below:

```
cat table_names
table:1234:nfl
table1:2345:nhl
table2:5555:nba
table3:3355:mls
table4:2463:echl
```

i also have a different table for each day of the week.

```
daya
dayb
dayc
dayd
daye
dayf
dayg
dayh
```

I have another file that tells me what the current table is for today

```
cat today_table
Today's active table is dayf
```

What I am trying to do is query each table prefix (table - table4) using the current active table for that day.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/ksh

active_table=$(today_table|awk '{print $5}')
prefix_table=$(cat table_names|grep -v ^#|awk -F":" '{print $1}'|sort -u)
today=`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`
OutPutDir="/tneal01/SPOOL"
OutPutFile="error"



Execsqlstatement1="select
to_char(current_date,'YYYYMMDD')  day,
count(*)                      Total
from ${prefix_table}.${active_table}
GROUP BY to_char(current_date,'YYYYMMDD')


#adding connection details here

$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus *********** << Eossql
    set lines 80
    set pages 50000
    set timing on
    spool tneal01/SPOOL/counts.`date +%Y-%m-%d`.tmp
    $Execsqlstatement1
    /
    spool off
    quit;
Eossql
grep "ORA-" $OutPutDir/$OutPutFile.$today.tmp
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "LOG MESSAGE sql select failed"


exit 0
```

The part am having issues with is the loop. I pretty much what the script to look at the current "active_table" and run the query on all five tables and spool the results to a file

example would be:

today's active table = dayg

```
select ***
from table.dayg
where .....

select ***
from table1.dayg
where .....

select ***
from table2.dayg
where .....

select ***
from table3.dayg
where ....

select ***
from table4.dayg
where .....
```

so then the spool file would look like

```
dayf table
Monday July 8th
table  count =31
table1 count =44
table2 count =33
table3 count =55
table4 count =23
```

Hopefully I explained this clearly.

EDIT: I can write this in Perl or shell. Both suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Thanks for reading!